# How to make a (buttons on)screen responsive while using relative layout in android studio?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, responsive, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to put buttons in a linear layout with self aligned spaces? I've been using relative layout, but the problem is that my screen does not remain responsive, so how do I make it responsive while using relative layout? Or else how can I add spaces in linear layout and place my buttons according to my height and width?

These are the output with both relative and linear layout. I've tried a lot by using different linear layouts, but it doesn't help as well.

[this is the output with relative layout,but it is not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mi9m.png)

[this is output with linear layout, where spaces are not being added by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIv4h.png)

Comment: You can try this using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)
Please share your XML code also so that someone can figure out what you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button One" />

    <android.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Two" />

    <android.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Three" />

    <android.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Four" />

    <android.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Five" />

    <android.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Taller Screen:**

[image]

**Shorter Screen:**

[image]